# How to throw a new exception in catch of the other?

Tags: java, exception

Oracle mentioned in its tutorial that once an exception is thrown you can throw a new exception. I do not know what it means. If I throw SampleException it should be caught somewhere, does it not?

[Following part is taken from Oracle website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html)

The following example shows how to use a chained exception.

```
try {

} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new SampleException("Other IOException", e);
}
```

In this example, when an IOException is caught, a new SampleException exception is created with the original cause attached and the chain of exceptions is thrown up to the next higher level exception handler.

Comment: What don't you understand about the code snippet?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis how SampleException is being caught? I am a bit confused as the rest of code is not shown.

Comment: How is the `IOException` exception (potentially) thrown within the `try` block caught? By a containing `catch` block. Somewhere, there is a `catch` block that will catch `SampleException`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that is the question, I need the rest of code! Where and how does it catch the exception? And in which cases do we need such chaining ?

Comment: sampleException will be thrown out to the outer try block.. Else the caller of this code.. In case of Main.. It will be thrown to the JVM.. Btw.. Removing oracle tag.. As it is only for DBMS..

Comment: The only way to `catch` and exception is to wrap code that throws an exception in a `try-catch`.

Comment: To let a higher level catch the exception shouldn't you straight up just add a throw declaration after your method name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have to handle the exception where ever you call this method. for example:

```
public class JavaTutorialsCorner {     
    public void testMethod() throws SampleException { 
        try {
            // some logic
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new SampleException("Other IOException", e); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

If you call this method somewhere else you must catch the thrown exception or re-throw it again

```
public class JavaTutorialsCornerWeb {         
    public void testMethodnew() {
        try {
            JavaTutorialsCorner jtc = new JavaTutorialsCorner();
            jtc.testMethod();        
        } catch (SampleException sx) {
            sx.printStackTrace();
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Its typo while doing copy & paste now removed

Comment: I'd just removed my comment after you corrected your source.